# Result of product with n=0

Tags: products

It's a simple question but I couldn't find informations about it and I'm starting to learn product sequences.

I noticed (using [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product_%28i%3D2%29%5E0+i)) that:

$\prod_{i=x}^{0}{f(i)}|_{x > 0} = 1$

Why is that? Shouldn't a sequence of zero products equals zero?

Ex :  $\prod_{i=x}^{0}{f(i)}|_{x > 0} = 0$?

Comment: Hint: What do you think a *sum* of zero terms should be equal to?

Comment: @Did I'd say zero?

Comment: Yes, the additive identity.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product

Comment: @TopinFrassi Yep, and since $\exp\sum=\prod$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want $\prod_{j=1}^n a_j = a_n\cdot\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}a_j$ to hold as generally as possible. The requires $a_1=\prod_{j=1}^1a_j=a_1\prod_{j=1}^0 a_j$, so the convention that the empty product equals $1$ is adequate. Compare also with $0!=1$ because there is exactly one way to arrange no objects, or with $x^0=1$.

Answer (score 1):

An empty product equals $1$. This is convenient for when the notation appears, for example, in the denominator.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Capital_Pi_notation